# How to make other JQuery run when a separate function runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the JS code below which filters based on checkboxes being checked or not (I don't think you need to see all the HTML because my question is rather simple/general, I think). All this code works fine, but I added a new function at the bottom (I noted it in the code) that simply has an uncheck all button for one of the sets of checkboxes (because there are like 30 checkboxes and I don't want the user to have to uncheck them all manually).

Anyway, the new script works properly too, except that the overall unrelated script that compares all checkboxes needs to run each time the new Uncheck All/Check All button is clicked.

Is there a simple way to make sure all the other JS runs when this new script is run?

I could be wrong, but I think I just need to somehow trigger this function inside the NEW FUNCTION:

```
$checkboxes.on('change', function() {
```

but am not sure how to do that.

ALL JS:

```
<script>
$(window).load(function(){

Array.prototype.indexOfAny = function(array) {
  return this.findIndex(function(v) {
    return array.indexOf(v) != -1;
  });
}

Array.prototype.containsAny = function(array) {
  return this.indexOfAny(array) != -1;
}



function getAllChecked() {

  // build a multidimensional array of checked values, organized by type

  var values = [];
  var $checked = $checkboxes.filter(':checked');

  $checked.each(function() {

    var $check = $(this);
    var type = $check.data('type');
    var value = $check.data('value');

    if (typeof values[type] !== "object") {
      values[type] = [];
    }

    values[type].push(value);

  });

  return values;

}

function evaluateReseller($reseller, checkedValues) {

  // Evaluate a selected reseller against checked values.
  // Determine whether at least one of the reseller's attributes for
  // each type is found in the checked values.

  var data = $reseller.data();
  var found = false;

  $.each(data, function(prop, values) {

    values = values.split(',').map(function(value) {
      return value.trim();
    });

    found = prop in checkedValues && values.containsAny(checkedValues[prop]);

    if (!found) {
      return false;
    }

  });

  return found;

}


var $checkboxes = $('[type="checkbox"]');
var $resellers = $('.Row');

$checkboxes.on('change', function() {

  // get all checked values.
  var checkedValues = getAllChecked();

  // compare each resellers attributes to the checked values.
  $resellers.each(function(k, reseller) {

    var $reseller = $(reseller);
    var found = evaluateReseller($reseller, checkedValues);

    // if at least one value of each type is checked, show this reseller.
    // otherwise, hide it.

    if (found) {
      $reseller.show();
    } else {
      $reseller.hide();
    }

  });

});


//NEW FUNCTION for "UNCHECK ALL" Button
$(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '#checkAll', function() {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Check All') {
      $('input.country').prop('checked', true);
      $(this).val('Uncheck All');
    } else {
      $('input.country').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).val('Check All');
    }
  });
});

});
```

New button HTML for the new UNCHECK portion:

```
<input id="checkAll" type="button" value="Uncheck All">
```

Answer (score 0):

I kept researching and discovered the trigger() function to handle this.
http://api.jquery.com/trigger/